# Extreme values of a multivariable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am studying  multivariable calculus and i don't know how to find the extreme values on a specific restriction ,i.e, $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 - z$ on the restriction $2x - 3y + z - 6 = 0$ . please help me this is an example in multivariable calculus Spivack.

Sorry for this question maybe is stupid but i need to understand the method for this exercises.

Comment: I try use lagrange theorem and find stationary points is that correct? please help

Comment: Do you know Lagrange multiplier method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** This is typical example using Lagrangian multiplier. Set
$$\mathcal{L}(x,y,z;\lambda)=x^2+y^2-z+\lambda(2x-3y+z-6)$$

Comment: and apply lagrange theorem ok thanks!

Comment: first i found partial in x,y,z,λ, then i put 4 equation solve them and find (x,y,z;λ)=(−1,3/2,25/2;1) is this extreme value?

Comment: @Knight Precisely.